# Unicode error: Tried everything

Tags: python, unicode

I have this piece of code which runs fine on pycharm ide but gives me an error when i run in the command line with output set to a file or as part of Elastic Map reduce. Tried everything but still doesnt work.

When i run it as python script.py in command line, it gives me the output. When i run it like python script.py > file , it gives me an error

```
  File "mapq4.py", line 48, in <module>
print ('%s,%s\t%s\t1\t%s\t%s' % (date, place, tag, tweetId, ind))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 19-28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can someone please help? I tried tag.encode('utf-8') and decode as well but I still get the error.

This is the output line at which it errors out at exactly the Korean characters I think:

```
2014-03-21,Bangkok  소녀시대미스터미스터  1   447027481703219202  57
```

This is part of a mapper function in EMR, so please keep that in mind as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  We are keen to help, but your question as it stands is not doing you any favours - as you can see it is being downvoted.   Please read the "how to ask a question" guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help , especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .   You may also benefit in underestanding how to work with unicode by reading this: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#1

Answer (score 0):

Python can usually detect the encoding of the IDE/console and can print non-ASCII characters without an issue, but when you redirect to a file Python doesn't know when the encoding should be and defaults to `ascii` on Python 2.x and `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` on Python 3.x.

Set the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` before redirecting to the file to let Python know what encoding to use.